# Loading a different .XIB when swipe to the left

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to figure out how to load a xib file when i use a gesture control when i wipe to the left then once that xib is presented on the screen i can then load a new xib file when i wipe to the left again is this possible?

for example: -

Page 1:
http://screensnapr.ryancouch.co.uk/photo%201.PNG

Page 2:
http://screensnapr.ryancouch.co.uk/photo%202.PNG

also theres more pictures if you delete the /photo%20x.png part on the provided url and how do i set up guesture controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible add left swipe gesture to every .xib that you want to swipe using left direction.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
[recognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
[recognizer release];
```

The left Swipe Handler will be

```
-(void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeGesture
{
 //Here add subview or navigate .xib left using swipe left
}
```

Comment: is it possible to go back to a xib once swiped left?

Comment: you will have to use right swipe gesture similarly to go back

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use a PageViewController instead of UISwipeGestures. It's a lot less code, and it will automatically instantiate your views.

Comment: Can i use the PageViewController to change through XIB's? because i got 4 xibs already made thinking it would be easier to just do them instead of doing it a different way